# Fetch data from sqlite database using AsyncTask or Alternative.The below is databasehelper class method how is asyncTask process created for it Thank

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

Public Curser getVocab(){String myPath=DB_PATH+DB_NAME;
SqliteDatabase db=SQLITEDatabase.openDatabase(         myPath,null,SQLITDatabase.OPEN_RED
ONLY);Cursor cc=db.rawQuery("select * from VOCAB",null);return cc;}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i mean the above is one of the method of the DatabaseHelper  class it fetches correctly  data from Assets Sqlite Database. But when i use it with AsyncTask it doesn't fetch data from sqlite database.                                                                                                                   And i am new and this is my first question sorry for the inconvenience